# How to replace all \n\t\n\ of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `cheerio` to do some simple scraping.

I want to scrape content from a website. I want to scrape it in HTML format, so I use `.html()` in `cheerio`.

```
const content = item.find(`div.message`).html()
```

And the result is a HTML source

```
\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tmua về độ lại xinhan khóa thông minh đèn thấy ok mà <img src=\"/images/smilies/Off/boss.gif\" border=\"0\" alt title=\"Boss\" class=\"inlineimg\">\n\t\t
```

I want to remove all the \n\t\n\n\t. The regex I use is

```
(\\t\\n|\\n|\\t)
```

I work perfectly on regex101 website. It matched all the\n\t\n in the string. But when I use the `replace` method in Javascript, it does not work.

```
const content = item.find(`div.message`).html().replace(/(\\t\\n|\\n|\\t)/, "")
```

The result still the same string with \n\t\n\n\t.

What do I need to change in the code?

**Updated more code**

I create a new file to test

```
const string =
  '\n\t\t\t<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE: ad_showthread_firstpost_start -->\n\n<!-- END TEMPLATE: ad_showthread_firstpost_start -->\n\t\t\ttính tết này súc em winner x , máy thím cho em ý kiến với <img src="/images/smilies/Off/pudency.gif" border="0" alt title="Pudency" class="inlineimg">\n\t\t';

console.log(string.replace(/(\\t\\n|\\n|\\t)/, ""));
```

The result will be the same

[image]

Comment: Why not keep the regex simple: `content.replace(/[\\t\\n]/g, '')`. Also, `"/(\\t\\n|\\n|\\t)/"` this is a string. Remove quotes to make it a regex object

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, but it still got the same result. It don't remove the \n\t\n\n...

Comment: Use this: a.replace(/\t|\n/g, '');

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH It still now work :(

Comment: I executed that code in the browser and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

keep it simple:

`.replace(/[\\n\\t]/g, '')`

Comment: That will replace new lines and tabs, not backslashes followed by n and t

Comment: just keep the double backslash then. edited